# How can I make an unknown UITextField resign first responder?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uiswitch

My view has two `UITextFields` and a `UISwitch`. If a user is edits a `textField`, and then immediately touches the switch (without pressing return), the text is left as they typed it, without `AutoCorrect`.

If I know which `textField` they were typing in, I can force the autocorrect to complete by calling `[textField resignFirstResponder]`. But the user could be typing in either `textField`, so I don't know which one to call.

How can I get around this? Is there a way of detecting which `textField` was being used? Or something simpler I haven't thought of?

Comment: Could you call resignFirstResponder on both textFields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [uitextfielddelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) methods are called for the textfield on which the editing is in progress. So that way you needn't be facing the problem of detecting which text field is being edited.

So implement the [uitextfielddelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) methods and assign the delegate of the text field to the class where you implement the methods and handle the responses in them.

The methods which you should be interested in are:

> **`textFieldDidEndEditing:`**
>
> Tells the delegate that editing stopped for the specified text field.
>
> `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *`textField`*
>             The text field for which editing ended.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status. You can use this method to update your delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method to hide overlay views that should be visible only while editing.
>      Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>
> `UITextField.h`

Answer (score 9):

One lovely way of doing this without having to keep track of which field is active:

```
// This causes the current responder (eg. an input field) to resignFirstResponder and
[self.endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Maybe Martin ment:`[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: @JPK: it works, but you have to take enreases comment into account

Comment: @rokjarc for me it does not work either (at least in `UITableViewController`). But jebins solution worked like charm, then

Answer (score 6):

Replace `[self.view endEditing:YES]`  with the below one...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

Comment: Very helpful when any view in the app might be the one that is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep track yourself which one is the current one, by using the textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate.